# Run bash in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, child-process

I need to start the `bash` terminal, sequentially execute several commands, collect their results and quit.
What is the correct way to do this in nodejs?

I tried to achieve this with `child_process.spawn` but it doesn't work as I have expected even with a single command.

Here is the simplified code:

```js
const process = spawn(`bash`, [])

// wait for the process to spawn
await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.once(`spawn`, resolve))

// log any output (expected to be the current node version)
process.stdout.on(`data`, data => console.log(data))

// wait for "node --version" to execute
await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.stdin.write(`node --version\n`, `utf8`, () => resolve()))

// wait for the process to end
await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.once(`close`, resolve))
```

The problem here is that I do not receive any outputs in `stdout` while `await process.once('spawn')` works fine.

I have logged `stderr` and every other event like `process.on` and `stdout.on('error')` but they are all empty. So I'm wondering what is the problem here.

In addition, google has tons of examples on how to run a **single** command. But I need to run **several** in the **same terminal**, wait between each call and collect individual results from `stdout`.
I'm not sure how to do this if this doesn't work as expected with the single command.

Comment: For running several commands, my preferred solution (from the viewpoint of maintainability) would be to put them into a shell script and run this script instead. This allows you to debug this set of commands independently from your node.js framework.

Comment: But I need to do this from the code and the commands are not known until runtime.
Also, I need to do some calculations between, like executing `node --version`, do something with the result from `stdout` and then executing second command.
So I'm afraid I can't do this outside js.

Comment: You have no idea what kind of commands you are running until runtime? So you can't use parameters to steer the script?

Comment: That's only part of the issue.
The biggest problem is that I need to extract some data from the first command and then feed it to the second one.
Like putting `16.0.1` from `node --version` into the `do_some_work.sh -v "16.0.1"`.
At the very end I need to do this inside js anyway. So the problem is that I don't know how to submit command to bash via `child_process`.

Comment: What is the sequence of commands that you want to run in the shell ?

Comment: It depends on the runtime.
In general I can receive a command from input or http request in order to execute it in the shell.

Comment: What is the main reason for wrapping the commands in a bash process? Why not use `exec("node --version", ...)`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that may cause the problem.  First is the last code executes `resolve()` right away allowing for the code execution to move to the next instructions immediately.  Second is `console.log(data)` might not be enough to print the output.  As I observed it, `data` is a `Buffer`, and not a string.

---

Please try this code and see if you get any useful message:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

async function main() {
  console.log("(console.log test)");
  const process = spawn(`bash`, [])

  // wait for the process to spawn
  await new Promise(resolve => process.once(`spawn`, resolve))

  // log any output (expected to be the current node version)
  process.stdout.on(`data`, data => console.log(data.toString()))
  
  // log any stderr
  process.stderr.on(`data`, data => console.log(data.toString()))

  // wait for "node --version" to execute
  await new Promise(resolve => process.stdin.write(`exec node --version\n`, `utf8`, () => resolve()))

  // wait for stdout and stderr stream to end, and process to close
  await Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => process.stdout.on('end', resolve)),
    new Promise(resolve => process.stderr.on('end', resolve)),
    new Promise(resolve => process.once(`close`, resolve))
  ])
}

main()
```

Comment: Yeah, the last `resolve()` was a typo.
Btw I think `console.log(Buffer.from('ololo'))` should be fine.
It will not give me the right string, but this will at least print something on the screen. But there is no output at all.

Comment: Does running `console.log("something")` outside the function work?

Comment: Yeah.
The main problem is that `process.stdout` is empty after `process.stdin.write` was executed.

Comment: What happens if you change `node` to `exec node`?

Comment: In fact nothing. It doesn't seem to work at all (the entire `stdin.write()`).
I didn't noticed that before. Thank You.

Comment: I'd also add a code that waits for `process.stdout` to end: `await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.stdout.on('end', resolve))`

Comment: @hopeless-programmer Have you tried my two last suggestions? How did you know `stdin.write()` didn't work?

Comment: Because I have no output in `stdout`.
My example here is reduced for simplification reason. But in the real code I have subscriptions for every event of `process`, `stdout` and `stderr`.
They all are silent.

Comment: You may have no output for stdout because allowed it to resolve `await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.once(`close`, resolve))` before the buffer gets flushed in `process.stdout`. That is why I made a suggestion to add `await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.stdout.on('end', resolve))`. Add it before the `close` handler, or have both them opened asynchronously but wrapped around a `Promise.all` call. You should also add a handler for the stderr so you can capture error messages just in case.

Comment: it doesn't help. Everything hangs on `await` for `stdout` end or `process` close regardless of the order.

Comment: And you tried `exec node`? I.e. `await new Promise<void>(resolve => process.stdin.write(\`exec node --version\n\`, \`utf8\`, () => resolve()))`. If `node` fails it should end quick.

Comment: Yes, I tried.
`resolve` on `stdin.write` works fine, but after this I don't have any outputs on any event.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer I updated my answer. Kindly try.

Comment: thanks, I tried it. I still don't have any output for `stdout`, but at least the last `await` works.

Comment: You ran the code as is right? Looks like that's all I can help.

Comment: Yes. The only change i have added is `<void>` for the `Promise` and `import` in order to be compatible with typescript and esmodules.
Thank You anyway!

Comment: Actually there's one more thing. Can you try specifying the `{ shell: true }` option to spawn? Also, try adding `-x` as an argument to `bash`.

Comment: It doesn't help. Do You have any output for `stdout`?

Comment: With my example above, I get `(console.log test)(newline)v14.17.6`. If you don't even see `console.log test`, something isn't right.

Comment: I'm running it with node.js.
I have `(console.log test)` output but I can't get the version string from `stdout`.

Comment: Try running it with other commands besides `bash` that produces an output, like `/bin/pwd`. Maybe `bash` just doesn't execute. Maybe `/bin/sh` doesn't even execute when `{ shell: true }` is specified. Look for some information on how to debug `process.spawn`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `shelljs` package and implement a helper function to run each command. Helper function:

```js
const shell = require('shelljs');

async function runShellCmd(cmd) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    shell.exec(cmd, async (code, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (!code) {
        return resolve(stdout);
      }
      return reject(stderr);
    });
  });
}

// run your commands here
```

In case of running multiple command in one instance, I would go with a `.sh` script:

- You can also use output of one command for the next one. I found an example here: https://linuxhint.com/bash_command_output_variable/
- You can also run `node file.js` to do additional processing (e.g. calculation, execute other commands, async/await queries) and then export the values needed for the environment to continue either via file or environment variables

Comment: Isn't this the same as running `child_process.exec` sequentially for each command?

Comment: if so, maybe it is better to write a shell script, and in there you can execute multiple commands:
- You can also use output of one command for the next one. I found an example here: https://linuxhint.com/bash_command_output_variable/
- You can also run `node file.js` to do something and inside the `file.js` can execute other commands, async/await queries, and then export additional values for the environment.

Comment: That's the last resort option.
It means that I need to use two "programming languages" (bash + js) instead of one (js).
I think there should be another way to do this with `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

When I follow the example provided by the [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) docs, everything seems to work fine.

> ```
> const { spawn } = require('child_process');
> const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
>
> ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
>   console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
> });
>
> ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
>   console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
> });
>
> ls.on('close', (code) => {
>   console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
> });
> ```

We can modify this example to use `bash` instead of `ls`. Then feed it some commands (via [`stdin.write()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback)) and [`end()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) the stream, so bash knows we are done writing.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bash = spawn('bash');

bash.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

bash.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

bash.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});

bash.stdin.write('node --version\n');
bash.stdin.write('npm --version\n');
bash.stdin.end();
```

When you run this script it produces (version numbers may differ):

```
stdout: v16.13.1

stdout: 8.1.2

child process exited with code 0
```

The reason for the empty lines is the fact that the command outputs include a newline at the end, `console.log()` adds an additional newline character on top.

I'm confused as to why you would go about doing this all through a `bash` process, when bash will end up creating different subprocesses. It feels like you are making things more complicated then they need to be.

---

A lot easier would be to use [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function main() {
  const { stdout: nodeVersion } = await exec('node --version');
  console.log("node version:", nodeVersion);
  const { stdout: npmVersion } = await exec('npm --version');
  console.log("npm version:", npmVersion);
}
main();
```

Which produces:

```
node version: v16.13.1

npm version: 8.1.2
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I can't get the output from the first command (`node --version`), process it and then feed to the next command (`npm --version`).
Also, here I need to `end()` the input (`stdin`) but in general it might be endless.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer [like I already asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579249/run-bash-in-node-js/70703294?noredirect=1#comment124981283_70579249): What is the main reason for wrapping all commands in a single bash process? This just seems really impractical. Why can't you use `exec('node --version')` or `exec('node --version', { shell: '/bin/bash' })` for that matter?

Comment: Because sometimes you need to maintain the context.
Execution of `node` and `1 + 2` in the single terminal is different from the execution in separate terminals.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer But if you need to maintain context wouldn't variables be stored in bash? eg. `current_date=$(date)` then `echo "today is $current_date"` In which case you can run all commands without regards of capturing output in node.js and injecting in a new command.

Comment: But running commands sequentially and getting the outputs is the point. I'm asking exactly for this.
If node.js or bash **can't accomplish** this I want to hear this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is, because I followed the docs, added a function returning a promise and it seems to work

> I need to start the `bash` terminal, sequentially execute several commands, collect their results and quit

`node` when run is a process, `bash` when run is a process, `ls` when run is a process, `rm` when run is a process.. the terminal spawns processes from its command line interface and **this below** spawns processes from node(with the same text used in terminal)

```js
let {spawn}=require('child_process') //spawn module
async function exec(command){
  return await new Promise(resolve=>{
    var toReturn="" //text to return
    let options={env:process.env,cwd:undefined,shell:true}
    let myChild=spawn(command,options)
    myChild.stdout.on('data',txt=>toReturn+=txt)
    myChild.stderr.on('data',txt=>toReturn+=txt)
    myChild.on('close',()=>resolve(toReturn))
  })
};
(async()=>{
  let ls_result=await exec('ls'), next_result=null
  if(someConditionBasedOn(ls_result)){next_result=await exec(if_true_cmd)}
  else{next_result=await exec(if_false_cmd)}
})()
```

Comment: The goal is not to run two separate processes, but to run a single one with several commands.

Comment: `await exec('bash someTxtFileWithAllYourCommands.txt')`

Comment: @hopeless-programmer I edited my answer to show it running several commands with one child process

Comment: I need to wait between separate commands and collect the outputs.

Comment: so.. u want to run commands separately, get data from each command BUT at the same time I can only spawn one child process?

Comment: Yes. The commands should be executed sequentially in the single process like in a "terminal".

Comment: @hopeless-programmer, Is it spawning some kind of interactive bash interpreter that you want? You'll need to create a fifo for that

Comment: @hopeless-programmer but the terminal spawns processes for the different tasks.. it reads a command and runs the process.. so if u say node..it runs node.. if u say npm it runs npm

Comment: @Fravadona sort of.
Does it mean that I can't achieve this with `exec` or `spawn`?
What exactly do You mean by FIFO? Is it some kind of queue between processes?

Comment: so lemme get this straight, my answer works but for some reason you want it in ONE process? that's like `node file1.js` and `node file2.js` and somehow they're NOT separate processes @hopeless-programmer

Comment: @hopeless-programmer, this may help you: https://github.com/ccnokes/node-fifo-example

Comment: @hopeless-programmer In the end, spawning a shell that run your commands is slower than spawning your commands independently, unless you make use of a lot of shell builtins, but in that case you could also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs instead

Answer (score 0):

First of all, executing a script with unknown parameters ahead of time sounds like you're using user input which opens yourself up to a host of vulnerabilities. Also always use absolute paths to avoid path poisoning. But let's assume you're properly sanitizing everything. You can use the `-c` argument with bash to specify what you want to run and separate your commands with `;`s.

Per the man file:

> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the  first
> non-option argument command_string.  If there are  arguments after the
> command_string, the first argument is   assigned  to $0 and any
> remaining arguments are assigned to  the positional parameters.  The
> assignment to $0 sets the  name of the shell, which is used in warning
> and error messages.

Here's an example that works fine for me

```js
#!/usr/bin/node
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

const magicString = '#@*$&#@*%&#@(#%@%#@';
const myScript = 'which_node=$(which node);' +
                 'node_ver=$($which_node --version);' +
                 'echo "where = $which_node";' +
                 'echo "version = $node_ver";' +
                 `echo '${magicString}';` +
                 'read foobar;' +
                 'echo $foobar;';

let cp = spawn('/usr/bin/bash', ['-c',myScript]);
cp.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
let data = '';
cp.stdout.on('data',(d) => {
  if(d.endsWith(magicString+'\n')) {
    d = d.substring(0,d.length-magicString.length-1);
    data += d;
    // do whatever with data
    cp.stdin.write('asdfasdsadfasdf\n');
  }
  else
    data += d;
});
cp.on('close',()=>console.log(data));
```

Output as expected:

```sh
$ ./test.js
where = /usr/local/bin/node
version = v14.18.1
asdfasdsadfasdf
```

Comment: I need to run the commands sequentially and read the output from `stdout`.
With this approach I can't tell what part of the output corresponds to the first command and what corresponds to the second.

Comment: I did that by placing the stdout in a bash variable

Comment: That looks like a dirty hack...
But still better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you need to alter what command you call second based on the output of what you call first? Or just that you need to supply the output from what you call first to what you call second?

Comment: Both.
In some cases I need to feed the output to the second command after preprocessing it with JavaScript.

Comment: Static preprocessing? You can add that to it's own js file and add it to the script or use a node eval call, i.e. `my_new_bash_var=$(node -e "console.log(JSON.parse($my_bash_var))")`

Comment: I can't believe this is really so complicated. It means that I need to execute separate js file inside the terminal while the terminal itself is already inside the js. That's madness.

Comment: Updated to include interactivity